# How can I upgrade 2e to use 3e armor rules?

Tags: dnd-3e, adnd-2e

Is it possible to only upgrade the 2nd edition Armor/Attack to the 3rd edition rules? I love the rest of the game mechanics over the 3rd edition rules, but I don't like how you have to subtract for attacking. That part can be very confusing to new players.

If so, how would you go about doing it? I want to make sure the game is still balanced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick and dirty tweak would be to flip THAC0 and AC related changes.

Armor adds to AC instead of subtracts, and every time your THAC0 would go down, you instead get a larger attack bonus.

5 AC (10-5) would then become 15 AC (10+5)

18 THAC0 would then become a +2 base attack bonus.

Both of those would equal a hit on a roll of a 13.

I obviously haven't tested this, but at quick glance it looks to me like it would preserve the balance of the game.

Comment: I like this solution. I'm going to try it out! Thanks!

Comment: This worked out perfect! Everyone enjoyed it quite a bit! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just make THAC0 and AC increase as the characters level up (the difference between 20 and the THAC0 is the to-hit bonus) and get better armour. The rest of the system with modifiers ect. will stay the same.

Comment: This is a good solution. I'm going to give it a shot and see. Thanks!